# Como se puede crear una JTable con 2 Columnas con Checkbox (Boolean) {Si y No}

Tags: java, netbeans, checkbox, jtable, radiobutton

**y que esten validadas para que si esta seleccionada una no este seleccionada la otra?**

Aunque no se si es mejor con el RadioButtom para selecciones unicas ambos funcionan igual tengo entendido, sin embargo en el entorno Grafico de NetBeans veo que existe el Buttom Group... sin embargo no se utilizarlo

Ademas en el modo grafico (modo diseño de formularios de netbeans) aparece en las opciones para configurar las tablas la opción para crear columnas de tipo boleano directamente.. sin embargo como se pueden validar estas para que una vez seleccionada una  la otra ya no pueda se seleccionar el otro, o si se selecciona uno el otro se deseleccione.. Buscare unas imagenes a ver si me hago entender mejor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Coloque 2 tablas en la ventana por la pregunta de como se puede colocar dentro de la tabla los radiobutton o los checkboxx o los combobox :S pero la principal duda es la primera.. jaja

Answer (score 1):

Hay dos opciones: la primera y mas sencilla es crear un TableModel heredado de AbstractTableModel en donde devuelvas un Boolean en el metodo getColumnClass(int col) asumiendo que col es la columna en donde aparecerá el jCheckBox.
La otra opción "vieja escuela" es crear un TableCellRenderer implementando la interface TableCellRenderer que herede del componente que desees (JRadioButton o JCheckbox) y setearle ese renderer al TableColumn del JTable en donde queres que se dibuje ese componente.
Para el caso puntual de la validación conjunta necesitarás usar la segunda opción y validar en el metodo getTableCellRendererComponent(argumentos).
**Un ejemplo del segundo caso seria:**

```
    private class MiJCheckBoxCellRenderer extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer{

          public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,int column) {

          //Aqui iran tus validaciones que, segun corresponda, haran this.setSelected(true o false);    
          return this;
    }
}
```

Luego en tu JTable obtendrás las columnas deseadas (para este caso la columna 2) y les asignarás tu nuevo CellRenderer de esta forma:

```
miJtable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(new PruebaCellRenderer());
```

Comment: Vaya ... o.o si entiendo gracias.. aunque no habia escuchado nada de ese TableCell Renderer en esa parte fue chino para mi jaja.. revise un poco pero no conegui muy buena información y la mas variadas estaba en ingles y no compredi muy bien.. podrias mostrarme algun codigo de ejemplo si no es mucho trabajo? y gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Agrego el ejemplo en la respuesta..