# Como seleccionar varias Filas en un JTABLE

Tags: java

Tengo una pregunta, estoy desarrollando un proyecto en java (netbeans) y necesito  seleccionar varias filas a la vez sin necesidad de teclear CTRL y seleccionar las filas, alguien podría ayudarme? (quiero que queden seleccionadas con un simple click en las filas).

Comment: ¿y no has probado a ponerle checkbox en la tabla? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/74830/como-se-puede-crear-una-jtable-con-2-columnas-con-checkbox-boolean-si-y-no

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que desarrollar en un metodo heredado del JTable.
Puedes hacerlo con cualquiera de estos

```
 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) { 
   // código que reacciona a la acción ... 
 }

 public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e) {
   saySomething ("Mouse presionado; # de clics:"
                + e.getClickCount (), e);
}

 public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) {
   saySomething ("Ratón pulsado (número de clics:"
                + e.getClickCount () + ")", e);
}
```

luego en cualquier método que uses tienes que guardar las posiciones seleccionadas y mostrar que dicha fila está seleccionada.

```
 int fila;
 int[] filaseleccionada;

    //metodo escogido
    try{
        //Guardamos en un entero la fila seleccionada.
        fila = table.getSelectedRow();
        filaseleccionada = new int[fila];
        if (filaseleccionada == -1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No ha seleccionado ninguna fila.");
        } else {
            table.setForeground(Color.RED);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias! thank so much